# Something's wrong with the vector ? Memory?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm testing some functions in c++ but when i used this code
it's compiling but my program fail with error  : std::bad_alloc
I think it's because i don't have enough memory or the vector is too bigger

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

int temps = time(0);
vector<int> vec(temps, 20);
for(int i(0); i < vec.size() ;i++){
    cout << vec[i] << endl;
};
}
```

Comment: Print out the value of `temps`. You may find it is *surprisingly* large.

Comment: `int i(0)` This seems wrong.

Comment: @AkshayArora, perfectly legal. C'tor syntax is valid for built-in types as well..

Comment: Is it? Well I learned something today. Thanks. @StoryTeller

Comment: yes, now i undersatnd my error the vector is too bigger and it's useless

Comment: Did you mean `vector<int> vec(20, temps);` ?

Comment: Besides I made a mistake.  thanks :-). I'm just starting learn c++

Answer (score 2):

`time(nullptr)` returns you the number of seconds since the 1st of January in 1970. Which is currently around 1458495645.
So you are currently initializing a std::vector with about 1.5 billion times the number 20 in. I guess you had a different intention.

Comment: Yes i just realize it's useless. Thanks for the answer